# Is materialized store created per partition and key or only per key?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have the following topology definition:

```
KStream<String, ObjectMessage> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream("topic1", "topic2");
stream.mapValues(new ProtobufObjectConverter())
        .groupByKey()
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.ofSizeWithNoGrace(Duration.ofMillis(100)))
        .aggregate(AggregatedObject::new, new ObjectAggregator(), buildStateStore(storeName))
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded().withMaxRecords(config.suppressionBufferSize())))
        .mapValues(new AggregatedObjectProtobufConverter())
        .toStream((key, value) -> key.key())
        .to(outputTopic);

private Materialized<String, AggregatedTicker, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> buildStateStore(String storeName) {
    return Materialized.<String, AggregatedObject, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(storeName)
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(new JsonSerde<>(AggregatedObject.class));
}
```

Both topics use the same key, but they mean different things. The question is, whether the keys put into store won't overwrite themself from different topics? I couldn't find easily such information in the code or documentation or didn't know where to particularly look to.

What I want to achieve is to possibly use single store across all topics and their partitions and be sure that state won't be corrupted or lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; the keys won't overwrite each other; keys from either topic will get included in the aggregation.

For some context, Kafka Streams creates a `Task` for each input partition.  So if you have a topic with 4 partitions, you'll get 4 tasks.  When you have multiple topics in the source, the number of tasks Kafka streams creates is max(topic1.partitions, topic2.partitions), and the task will process records from the same partition from each topic.  For example, let's assume `topic1` and `topic2` each have 4 partitions - you'll end up with 4 tasks  `0_0, 1_1, 2_2, 3_3`, the first number is the task-id, and the second number is the partition it's responsible for.

So the `groupByKey` will group keys from either topic since all the records the task is processing belong to the nth partition.  If you want to treat records differently by topic, you'll need to use the [KStream.process](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.2/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier-java.lang.String...-) method, which gives you access to the [ProcessorContex](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.2/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html). From the `ProcessorContext`, you can use the `recordMetadata()` method to retrieve the [RecordMetadata](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.2/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/api/RecordMetadata.html) object from which you can get the source topic for that particular record.  In some cases, the topic name might not be available as explained in the [RecordMetadata.topic(](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/3.3.2/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/api/RecordMetadata.html#topic--)) Javadoc.

HTH,

Bill